# Daemon Failed to start error

Tags: daemon

I recently started learning about monero and exchanged some BTC to XMR and sent to my Monero GUI wallet.  For some reason, when the network synchronization was happening, my computer crashed.  Now, when I log in, I get an error message every time the Daemon tris to start.  Does anyone have any advice?  I am scared I am gonna lose my exchange.

Answer (score 2):

When asking for help about a particular error, it is a good idea to include that message. After all, we're not omniscient.

Your blockchain is probably corrupted, which will require a sync from scratch. This does not risk your monero being lost, though. Once you've synced again, your wallet will see your monero just fine.

monerod uses a faster, but more risky sync mode when downloading the chain. It usually works fine, but is prone to this sort of corruption when the OS/computer crashes. If your computer often does this sort of thing and you can't change the OS (or hardware if it's a hardware fault), you can force a safer sync mode (though it may be a lot slower):

`monerod --db-sync-mode safe:async:1000`

Once the initial sync is complete, monerod will automatically switch to this safer mode, as database speed is less of an issue then.