# daemon error: Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, blockchain, daemon, linux, deterministic-wallet

following up with [starting](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/13322/14165) a recovered wallet:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ monerod --prune-blockchain
2023-05-20 11:00:30.349 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-unknown)
2023-05-20 11:00:30.349 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2023-05-20 11:00:30.349 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2023-05-20 11:00:30.349 I Initializing core...
2023-05-20 11:00:30.350 I Loading blockchain from folder /home/nicholas/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2023-05-20 11:00:30.388 I Loading checkpoints
2023-05-20 11:00:30.388 I Core initialized OK
2023-05-20 11:00:30.388 I Initializing p2p server...
2023-05-20 11:00:30.395 F Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)
2023-05-20 11:00:30.397 I Deinitializing core...
2023-05-20 11:00:30.421 I Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2023-05-20 11:00:30.421 I Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
2023-05-20 11:00:30.421 E Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

I've recovered a deterministic wallet by entering the twenty five word seed and am not seeing any balance.  From recollection, there's something about connecting to a node, if that's the correct terminology.

```
[wallet 42mEMY]: 
[wallet 42mEMY]: balance
Currently selected account: [0] Primary account
Tag: (No tag assigned)
Balance: 0.000000000000, unlocked balance: 0.000000000000
[wallet 42mEMY]: 
[wallet 42mEMY]: status
Refreshed 1/1, synced, daemon RPC v1.13, no SSL
[wallet 42mEMY]: 
[wallet 42mEMY]: refresh
Error: Daemon uses a different RPC major version (1) than the wallet (3): http://localhost:18081. Either update one of them, or use --allow-mismatched-daemon-version.
[wallet 42mEMY]:
```

The daemon isn't connecting to the blockchain?

I [also](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/6616/14165) tried:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ monerod --db-sync-mode safe:async:1000
2023-05-20 11:24:27.528 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-unknown)
2023-05-20 11:24:27.528 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2023-05-20 11:24:27.528 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2023-05-20 11:24:27.529 I Initializing core...
2023-05-20 11:24:27.529 I Loading blockchain from folder /home/nicholas/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2023-05-20 11:24:27.612 I Loading checkpoints
2023-05-20 11:24:27.631 I Core initialized OK
2023-05-20 11:24:27.631 I Initializing p2p server...
2023-05-20 11:24:27.638 F Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)
2023-05-20 11:24:27.641 I Deinitializing core...
2023-05-20 11:24:27.650 I Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2023-05-20 11:24:27.651 I Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
2023-05-20 11:24:27.651 E Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server.
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

I have a vague recollection of configuring the daemon but don't recall how that was accomplished.

Comment: `Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-unknown)` that is an old version. Current version is `v0.18.2.2`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work now:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ monerod --db-sync-mode safe:async:1000
2023-05-20 11:29:04.248 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-unknown)
2023-05-20 11:29:04.248 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2023-05-20 11:29:04.248 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2023-05-20 11:29:04.249 I Initializing core...
2023-05-20 11:29:04.249 I Loading blockchain from folder /home/nicholas/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2023-05-20 11:29:04.360 I Loading checkpoints
2023-05-20 11:29:04.394 I Core initialized OK
2023-05-20 11:29:04.394 I Initializing p2p server...
2023-05-20 11:29:04.400 I p2p server initialized OK
2023-05-20 11:29:04.400 I Initializing core RPC server...
2023-05-20 11:29:04.401 I Binding on 127.0.0.1 (IPv4):18081
2023-05-20 11:29:08.060 I core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081
2023-05-20 11:29:08.088 I Starting core RPC server...
2023-05-20 11:29:08.089 I core RPC server started ok
2023-05-20 11:29:08.089 I Starting p2p net loop...
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I 
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I **********************************************************************
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. This may take a long time to complete.
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I 
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I You can set the level of process detailization through "set_log <level|categories>" command,
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I where <level> is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING).
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I 
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I Use "help <command>" to see a command's documentation.
2023-05-20 11:29:09.091 I **********************************************************************
```

after [killing](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/12962/14165) the `monerod` process.

However, it seems to be a large download.

Comment: `Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-unknown)` that is an old version. Current version is `v0.18.2.2`.